# Multivariate polynomial data fitting formula

Tags: interpolation

A short description：

consider $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$

we can know that $f(1,0,1)=0,f(0,1,1)=0$ ,etc.

so we can get the roots of this polynomial.

Now if given the roots of polynomial, how to solve the most possibly polynomial?

---

I have some interdependent data.There is a multivariate polynomial  relationship between known data.

like : $\{a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i, e_i\} , 1 \le i \le 30$.

I want to generate a polynomial like : `f[a, b, c, d, e] == 0`。 
 The highest degree of polynomials  f is no more than 5.

```
date = {{1.7959, 4.05481, 0.557256, 0.748305, -1.03845}, {0.0858696, 
    1.07169, 0.705519, 1.32677, -0.855295}, {4.90172, 0.158416, 
    0.878733, 1.96608, 954.245}, {2.27961, 1.71061, 1.44171, 
    0.69401, -1.84901}, {0.256048, 4.24589, 0.652135, 
    0.314675, -2.26791}, {0.016098, 3.35303, 0.0255727, 
    0.930836, -0.0371771}, {4.55962, 2.4236, 1.92493, 1.51859, 
    0.626972}, {4.64569, 4.67848, 1.69821, 
    1.35355, -1.3203}, {1.21131, 3.76428, 0.680899, 
    0.181542, -4.12665}, {3.52003, 4.06811, 0.153511, 
    1.118, -0.0969514}, {0.873221, 3.97128, 1.08425, 
    1.69994, -0.934625}, {2.06676, 3.31185, 1.81121, 
    1.937, -1.28445}, {3.23805, 0.966946, 0.420946, 0.341141, 
    7.18288}, {2.38365, 3.96166, 1.56003, 
    0.846376, -2.30139}, {2.70938, 0.336656, 0.0891704, 1.18989, 
    62.8609}, {4.29624, 0.725231, 0.313328, 1.99668, 
    33.2428}, {4.69485, 3.30499, 0.440388, 1.83629, 
    0.779267}, {1.98956, 3.55388, 0.252933, 
    1.08482, -0.403182}, {2.01274, 4.62648, 1.06508, 
    1.7516, -0.901361}, {2.68855, 0.445539, 1.045, 1.38863, 
    33.6256}, {0.758261, 3.13808, 1.90326, 
    0.687971, -3.40373}, {3.05937, 0.0417194, 1.30474, 1.56848, 
    5374.06}, {0.729741, 0.942849, 0.990381, 
    0.803124, -1.61932}, {3.86653, 3.23461, 1.45103, 
    1.27452, -0.888884}, {4.21975, 3.5693, 1.78065, 
    1.96737, -0.591169}, {3.7998, 2.03796, 1.84843, 
    0.0281808, -64.849}, {4.78858, 4.16817, 0.255213, 0.861542, 
    0.0208193}, {2.49005, 0.608272, 0.556096, 0.453426, 
    12.6624}, {1.69236, 0.85002, 0.114269, 1.89718, 
    3.24608}, {1.37257, 0.451485, 0.291911, 1.00561, 7.80971}};
```

I want to know how to find formulas from data.

The answer I expect is  `- b^3 c + a^2 b d - a b^2 d - 2 b^2 c d + 
 a^2 d^2 - b^3 d e - b^2 d^2 e`.

Because I generated the data according to this formula.

I have tried [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html), but since f==0, so it will just return 0.

---

Comment: i am confused as what are the parameters and what are the variables. normally, letters like $x,y,z$ etc.. are used for variables and letters like $a,b,c$ etc... are used for parameters. I see here only $a,b,c$ and no $x,y,z$. Is this meant to be a polynomial in $x$ only?